# PHP: Get Real Image Path From STRING

Tags: php, regex, string

```
<?php
$string = "http://giphy.com/static/img/homepage_banners/snl-leslie.gif";

$find_images = preg_match("/(https?:\/\/\S+\.(?:jpg|png|jpeg|gif))\s+/", $string, $matches) ? $matches[1] : "";

if(@is_array(getimagesize($find_images))) {
    // Check if image exists
    echo $find_images;
}
?>
```

I try to echo image link but my regex not find link of image. ???  can someone help me? thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a `\s+` at the end of the string, which will try to match one or more spaces, but your input string doesn't have any. Remove it as

```
/(https?:\/\/\S+\.(?:jpg|png|jpeg|gif))/
```

[**Regex Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/WqV3Op/1)

Comment: Thank you so much.